# Linq return datetime from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure named SQLBackupStatusLastRanDate and it returns a single datetime named EventDateTime.

Within my VB.net app I have added in a DataContextClass and added the stored procedure to that.  I have two lines of code (shown below) which I want to return the date in to a variable.

```
Dim logon As New LogonAuditDataClassDataContext
Dim backupRanTime As DateTime = logon.SQLBackupStatusLastRanDate("EventDateTime")
```

The error message is that it cannot be converted to a date.

If I dont declare the variable type as shown below

```
Dim logon As New LogonAuditDataClassDataContext
Dim backupRanTime = logon.SQLBackupStatusLastRanDate("EventDateTime")
```

I get the error

> Conversion from string "EventDateTime" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

I am sure this should be easy and I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Please add definition of `LogonAuditDataClassDataContext.SQLBackupStatusLastRanDate()`

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean

Comment: Your SqlBackupStatusLastRanDate has a return value of some type. You try to assign the returned value to a variable of another type. Apparently these types are not the same, because your error message says that it cannot convert the returned type to the type you want to assign the returned value to. Chris asked to extend your problem description with the definition of SQLBackupStatusLastRanDate, especially the return type. If the error is not upon returning, show the statement where the erroneous conversion is reported.

Answer (score 0):

After some playing about I changed the code to:

```
Dim logon As New LogonAuditDataClassDataContext
Dim backupRanTime = logon.SQLBackupStatusLastRanDate().First.EventDateTime
```

This works as expected.